# Foreach loop inside array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to create an array inside an array, using a for loop - here's my code:

```
    array(
    'label' => 'Assign to user',
    'desc' => 'Choose a user',
    'id' => $prefix.'client',
    'type' => 'radio'
    'options' => array( 
        foreach ($clients as $user) {
         $user->user_login => array (  
            'label' => $user->user_login,  
            'value' => $user->user_login,
            ), 
        }
        )
    )
```

Unfortunately this gives me a

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING,
>   expecting ')'"

For the line:

```
'options' => array(
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what has gone wrong - any help is much appreciated. $clients is defined elsewhere, so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's invalid syntax. You'd have to build the "parent" portions of the array first. THEN add in the sub-array stuff with the foreach loop:

```
$foo = array(
    'label' => 'Assign to user',
    'desc' => 'Choose a user',
    'id' => $prefix.'client',
    'type' => 'radio',
    'options' => array()
);

foreach ($clients as $user) {
    $foo['options'][] = array (  
        'label' => $user->user_login,  
        'value' => $user->user_login,
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me as the array foo, is in an array itself which gives the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH, expecting ')'

Comment: You don't need to make 'options' an `array()` if there is a chance it won't be filled. That may throw off some parsers to see an empty value (ie, schema json-ld).

Comment: Thank you for the simple and very clear way of explaining.

Answer (score 2):

You use foreach to access the data, not define it.

Try this:

```
array(
    'label' => 'Assign to user',
    'desc' => 'Choose a user',
    'id' => $prefix.'client',
    'type' => 'radio'
    'options' => $clients
    )
```

If you need to change the structure of the data for 'options', do this before defining the primary array.

Comment: With this approach, how would I go about making $clients be an array of arrays? sorry if this sounds a little dense!

Comment: Define $clients first

[`code`]$clients = array(array('oneval', 'two'), array('another', 'another'));[/`code`]

then just include $clients in your primary array

Comment: but I need to get the values by using a foreach loop as clients is used for a wordpress query: $clients = get_users();

Comment: Then make sure you've populated an array with the structure you expect and assign it to $clients - or try Marc's answer; same approach, different order

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by that, unfortunately Marc's code does not work in my situation (see comment), thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the foreach in the definition of the array. You can however put the `$clients` variable in the array itself or you can foreach outside the array to build the array to be inserted at the `options` key