# How to use the foreach inside array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to do foreach inside array.
I am trying to generate the select box using array value everything seems ok when i give a value manually.

```
array(
    'name' => __('Testing Selection', 'test'),
    'id' => 'testing',
    'css' => 'min-width:150px;',
    'std' => '2', 
    'default' => '2',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => array(
        '1' => __('Test1', 'test'),
        '2' => __('Test2', 'test'),
        '3' => __('Test3', 'test'),
    ),
),
```

In the above code options key contains three values like 1, 2, 3 and the above code is working. But i want to loop all product id here using foreach but it seems not working for me may be i am trying a wrong way.  I know foreach inside array is invalid that's why i am trying this way.

```
$foos = array(
    'name' => __('Testing Selection', 'test'),
    'id' => 'testing',
    'css' => 'min-width:150px;',
    'std' => '2', 
    'default' => '2',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => array(),
),
```

After array i did foreach

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => '-1');
$getproducts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($getproducts as $product) {
    $foos['options'][] = array(
        $product->ID => $product->get_title,
    );
}
```

I want to list 20 more products in the select box everything manually is hard to me can anyone suggest me to use the foreach inside array?

Comment: What do you want the end result to be?

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) End result should be list of product id with name in a select box.

Comment: How do you want the end array to look.

Comment: Can you please check this link here is the similar method i am trying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446174/foreach-loop-inside-array

Comment: What is the current end value of `$foos` and what do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PHP functions like [array_map()](http://www.php.net/array_map) or [array_reduce()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) you can create the new array inside an array. array_map () is useful for creating the values ​​for an array, but you can not manipulate the keys with it. Because of that we can use array_reduce() to simulate the behavior of array_map() and to create the associative array needed for options.

```
$foos = array(
    'name'      => 'Testing Selection',
    'id'        => 'testing',
    'css'       => 'min-width:150px;',
    'std'       => '2', 
    'default'   => '2',
    'type'      => 'select',
    'options'   => array_reduce( get_posts( 'post_type=product&posts_per_page=-1' ), function( $result, $item ) { 
        $result[$item->ID] = $item->post_title;
        return $result;
    })
);
```

If you don't like the approach, you can create new function that will return the required array for options, and thus improve the readability of code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you have in mind, but try this template:

```
<select>
<?php
    $items = array(
        'one' => 'Item one',
        'two' => 'Item two',
        'three' => 'Item three'
    );
    foreach(array_keys($items) as $item_id) {
        echo "<option name=\"$item_id\">$items[$item_id]</option>\n";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your template :) 
 
Can you please check this link here is the similar method i am trying stackoverflow.com/questions/14446174/foreach-loop-inside-array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert data to database , then you should go with foreach key value combination.
Here given the example

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $myArray = array();
    $myArray = array(
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'contact' => $_POST['contact'],
        'address' => $_POST['address']
    );

    foreach($myArray as $key=>$value){
        echo $value;
    }
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            name<input type="text" name="name"/>
            contact<input type="text" name="contact"/>
            address<input type="text" name="address"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```