# Foreach loop inside WP filtering system

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create custom filters for my users. Here is what i am trying to do which doesn't work:

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'books',
    'meta_key'   => 'product_title',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'options' => array()
);

foreach ($myurlfilter as $multifilter) {
    $args['options'][] = array (
        'key' => 'product_title',
        'value' => "$multifilter",
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    );
}
```

I don't get any php error and i don't know what i am doing wrong. I did made my code according to this answer: [Foreach loop inside array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446174/foreach-loop-inside-array) and if you check the last comment of the author at below answer it say "code does not work".

From the output i see, i believe the options from foreach code are not "connecting" properly  with code above it.

If that helps what i am trying to achieve with foreach is something like this, which works perfect:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'books',
    'meta_key'   => 'product_title',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'product_title',
            'value'     => 'Leonardo',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'product_title',
            'value'     => 'Einstein',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Your foreach should add to an array, who's first value is the "relation or" syntax, whicn you can then append to the meta query argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building your meta query with the starting "or"

```
$myMeta = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );

foreach ($myurlfilter as $multifilter) {
    $myMeta[] = array (
        'key' => 'product_title',
        'value' => $multifilter,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    );
}

$args['meta_query'][] = $myMeta;
```

I also belive you need to ditch "options" and add to "meta_query"

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'books',
    'meta_key'   => 'product_title',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array() // change this, remove the relation
);
```